# What is the preimage of a function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it the domain of the inverse or the defined domain of the inverse (in the case the function is not invertible)? The concept is very confusing for some reason I cannot grasp.

Answer (score 8):

I would not use the terminology *preimage of a function* at all. If $f:X\to Y$ is a function, and $A\subseteq Y$, the *preimage of* $A$ *under* $f$ is $$f^{-1}[A]=\big\{x\in X:f(x)\in A\big\}\;.$$ That is, in my terminology subsets of the codomain of $f$ have preimages under $f$, and these preimages are subsets of the domain of $f$.

You can, if you wish, define a function $$f^{\leftarrow}:\wp(Y)\to\wp(X):A\mapsto f^{-1}[A]$$ that takes each subset of $Y$ to its preimage in $X$ under the function $f$, but I would never call this function the preimage of $f$..

Comment: Is your point that the phrase '_preimage of a function_' directly ignores and implies the opposite of the fact that the preimage requires a **set** for the argument of a function?

Comment: I don't quite understand. In layman's terms, how would you define it?

Comment: @Limitless: Not really. My point is that it isn’t the function that has a preimage; the function is the mechanism by which preimages of subsets of the codomain are constructed.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I misphrased what I was trying to say, sorry. In my comment, I meant $f^{-1}$ by 'function'. That is, $A$ is the argument in $f^{-1}[A]$.

Comment: @xeonphi: As I said, I wouldn’t: given a function $f:X\to Y$, I don’t consider the expression *the preimage of* $f$ meaningful. Subsets of $Y$ have preimages under $f$.

Comment: @Limitless: You can always view $f^{-1}$ as a function from $\wp(Y)$ to $\wp(X)$; from that point of view it’s the $f^{\leftarrow}$ of my answer. For each $A\subseteq Y$ it gives you the preimage of $A$ under $f$. None of that is problematic. What I’m saying is that at least as I (was taught to) use the words, ‘the preimage of $f$’ is meaningless: $f$ doesn’t have a preimage. Subsets of $Y$ have preimages, and specifically preimages under $f$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, I understand perfectly now. You've made a very good point.

Answer (score 7):

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function. Let $A\subset X$ and $B\subset Y$. Then $f(A)=\{f(x)\in Y:x\in A\}$ is called the image of $A$ under $f$ and $f^{-1}(B)=\{x\in X:f(x)\in B\}$ is called the preimage of $B$ under $f$.

Answer (score 4):

If $f\colon A\to B$ is a function (any function) then the preimage is actually a function $\tilde f\colon P(B)\to P(A)$ (where $P$ indicates the power set) defined as follows: $$\tilde f(X)=\{a\in A\mid f(a)\in X\}$$

Note that the domain of $f$ is $A$ so $A$ itself is $\tilde f(B)$, however it is possible that $\tilde f$ is neither surjective nor injective in cases where $f$ fails to satisfy some of these properties.